# cameracalibrator.py error

Tags: ros, calibration, monocular-camera, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to follow the ROS tutorial titled: "How to Calibrate a Monocular Camera", [link](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/MonocularCalibration) I am using the gscam driver and have verified that it is publishing correctly. Also steps 1.1-1.3 executed without error, but at step 1.4 when I enter:

```
rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.108 image:=/camera/image_raw camera:=/camera
```

I get:

```
('Waiting for service', '/camera/set_camera_info', '...')
Service not found

(display:17709): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing fundamental type 'gchar' (as 'gchar')
**
GLib-GObject:ERROR:/build/buildd/glib2.0-2.40.0/./gobject/gvaluetypes.c:455:_g_value_types_init: assertion failed: (type == G_TYPE_CHAR)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

If I run it with the "--no-service-check" option, I get:

```
Exception in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/share/camera_calibration/nodes/cameracalibrator.py", line 93, in run
    self.function(m)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/share/camera_calibration/nodes/cameracalibrator.py", line 161, in handle_monocular
    checkerboard_flags=self._checkerboard_flags)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/camera_calibration/calibrator.py", line 525, in __init__
    super(MonoCalibrator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'checkerboard_flags'

Killed
```

If it helps below is the output of "rostopic list"

```
/camera/camera_info
/camera/image_raw
/camera/image_raw/compressed
/camera/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/image_raw/compressedDepth
/camera/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/image_raw/theora
/camera/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/rosout
/rosout_agg
```

Any help would be appreciated, I'm running this on Indigo, Ubuntu 14.04

Edit: Output from "rosservice list"

```
/camera/image_raw/compressed/set_parameters
/camera/image_raw/compressedDepth/set_parameters
/camera/image_raw/theora/set_parameters
/cameracalibrator/get_loggers
/cameracalibrator/set_logger_level
/gscam_publisher/get_loggers
/gscam_publisher/set_logger_level
/rosout/get_loggers
/rosout/set_logger_level
/set_camera_info
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190126/cameracalibrator.py-error/) by [RF](https://answers.ros.org/users/19444/rf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-08-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-13**:
I suspect the /camera/set_camera_info service doesn't exist, or isn't remapped properly. Can you add the output of `rosservice list` to your question please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The service `/set_camera_info` mentioned in your edit needs to be remapped to `/camera/set_camera_info` .

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0